# mysql gis poylgon insert fail

Tags: mysql, insert, gis, polygon

i'm a brazilian, and have a project that I using Google Maps API + GWT + MySQL but, i've problem, i can't create a polygon geometry in BD with more then 3 decimal places.

If I run the query:

```
INSERT INTO monografia.locais (nome,descricao,tags, geo)
VALUES ('test','this is a polygon','dfaf asdf asdf',
        GeomFromText(
           'POLYGON((-19.863924936000608 -43.887290954589844,
                     -19.84810225157064 -43.97758483886719, 
                     -19.893951403349405 -44.011573791503906, 
                     -19.92945922975802 -44.01466369628906, 
                     -25.065697185535864 -40.62744140625, 
                     -19.863924936000608 -43.887290954589844))
            '))
```

return null to me, but if I rounding to 2 decimal places it's work:

```
INSERT INTO monografia.locais (nome,descricao,tags, geo)
VALUES ('doidera','é um poligono doidera','dfaf asdf asdf',
        GeomFromText(
           'POLYGON((-19.86 -43.88, 
                     -19.84 -43.97, 
                     -19.89 -44.01, 
                     -19.92 -44.01, 
                     -25.06 -40.62, 
                     -19.86 -43.88))
            '))
```

But I need a better precision, more then 2 decimal places.
Someone can help me ?

Comment: I was not able reproduce your problem. I started with a table "create table t (geo shape)" and was able to do the insert you outlined. Can you provide the output of "desc monografia.locais" ? What is the data-type of your "geo" column?